# PL SQL error in my VB.Net code but can't reproduce in SQL Developer

Tags: vb.net, oracle, plsql

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
>       ORA-06512: at "JOHN.GET_USERS_EMAIL", line 7
>       ORA-06512: at line 1

When I run my procedure in SQL Developer and use the values in my app, it works without any problem. When I run my VB.Net code, I get the exception (shown above)

I don't know what I am doing incorrectly. (The Oracle Procedure was not written by me. It was by another person who is no longer working here).

Procedure in Oracle

```sql
create or replace PROCEDURE "GET_USERS_EMAIL" (
User_Email_P OUT VARCHAR,
Employee_P IN VARCHAR
)
As 
Begin
SELECT USER_EMAIL INTO User_Email_P FROM
EMPLOYEE
WHERE
USER_ID = Employee_P;
end;
```

Code in VB.Net

```vb
Public Function Get_A_Users_Email(ByVal strEmpId As String) As String
    Try
        Dim rValue As String = ""
        Dim strSQL As String = "JOHN.GET_USERS_EMAIL"
        Dim cmd As OracleCommand = dba.CreateStoredProcCommand(strSQL)
        cmd.BindByName = True
        Dim oracleParameter(1) As OracleParameter
        oracleParameter(0) = New OracleParameter()
        oracleParameter(1) = New OracleParameter()
        strEmpId = UCase(strEmpId.Trim())

        With cmd
            oracleParameter(0) = cmd.Parameters.Add(name:="User_Email_P", dbType:=OracleDbType.Varchar2, direction:=ParameterDirection.Output)
            oracleParameter(1) = cmd.Parameters.Add(name:="Employee_P", dbType:=OracleDbType.Varchar2, val:=strEmpId, ParameterDirection.Input)

        End With

        dba.ExecuteScaler(cmd)

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(cmd.Parameters("User_Email_P").Value.ToString) = True Then
            rValue = 0
        Else
            rValue = cmd.Parameters("User_Email_P").Value.ToString
        End If

        Return rValue
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim Err As New App_Errors("App_Users", "Get_A_Users_Email", ex)
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Function

Public Function ExecuteScaler(ByVal cmd As OracleCommand) As String
    ' the value tobe return ...
    Dim value As String = ""
    Dim oValue As Object
    Dim bValue As Boolean = False
    ' execute command ...
    Try
        ' open connection ...
        cmd.Connection.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to establish a connection to CFR database." & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
        Return value = ""
        Exit Function
    End Try
    Try

        ' execute command ... convert type in the case of return value null ...
        oValue = cmd.ExecuteScalar
        bValue = Convert.IsDBNull(oValue)
        If Not (bValue) Then
            value = CType(oValue, String)
        Else
            value = ""
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        ' rethrow error ...
        ' Dim Err As New App_Errors("Data_Access_Class", "ExecuteScalar", ex)
        Throw New Exception(ex.InnerException.ToString, ex)
    Finally
        cmd.Connection.Close()
    End Try
    Return value
End Function

Public Function CreateStoredProcCommand(ByVal cmdtext As String) As OracleCommand
    Dim Cmd As New OracleCommand        ' command object ...
    ' create command ...
    With Cmd
        .Connection = Conn
        .CommandText = cmdtext
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    End With
    Return Cmd
End Function
```

Here is the DDL of the table.

```
CREATE TABLE "JOHN"."EMPLOYEE" 
   (    "EMPLOYEE_NUMBER" NUMBER(9,0), 
    "LOCATION_CODE" VARCHAR2(4 BYTE), 
    "SECURITY_LEVEL" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "DATE_LAST_UPDATE" DATE, 
    "DATE_SECURITY_ASSIGNED" DATE, 
    "LAST_PASSWORD_DATE" DATE, 
    "CURRENT_PASSWORD" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    "MIDDLE_INITIAL" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE), 
    "USER_ID" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "USER_TYPE" CHAR(1 BYTE), 
    "INACTIVE_DATE" DATE, 
    "SECURITY_ASSIGNED_BY" VARCHAR2(8 BYTE), 
    "PASSWORD_EXPIRATION_DATE" DATE, 
    "STATUS_CODE" NUMBER(2,0), 
    "ACCOUNT_LOCKED" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "UPDATE_PASS_ON_SIGNON" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "USER_EMAIL" VARCHAR2(30 BYTE))
```

Please note that the DDL, Stored Procedures and VB.Net code was left from a previous developer. I am replacing the Microsoft's implementation of Oracle's driver to ODP.Net. There is literally no change in code other than this.

Comment: Thanks @djv ofr reformatting. Can you help out?

Comment: What is the type of the USER_ID Field in the db?  The error suggests that it's numeric but in the Param you're sending it through as varchar

Comment: @softwareisfun I was hoping proper syntax coloring would help others to help you... I don't deal in Oracle at all. I do know that `ExecuteScaler` should be spelled `ExecuteScalar` but that's not very helpful. Past that I don't know much. Good luck! :)

Comment: User_ID is VARCHAR2

Answer (score 0):

Keep your database objects local to the method where they are used. That way you can control when they are closed and disposed. Connections and commands may contain unmanaged code which needs to be released by their respective `.Dispose` methods. In this example a `Using...End Using` block handles this for you even if there is an error.

I am not sure why you are creating the stored procedure again when you state that is is already in Oracle.

Your do quite a dance with the parameters creating an array of parameters then assigning values to the array elements. The Parameter.Add method automatically adds the parameter to the Parameters Collection. You are using named parameters but you are not using the proper names. To avoid this problem just use positional parameters.

Now we get to the actual .Execute. `.ExecuteScalar` returns the first column of the first row of the result set. I don't think you can refer to your Out parameter in this scenario. Without a cursor in the stored procedure I am not sure any result set is returned.

Try an `.ExecuteNonQuery` and then retrieve the parameter value. Notice that my database objects are closed and disposed by the End Using before I start checking the returned value.

I cannot test this because I don't have an installation of Oracle hanging around.

```
Public Function Get_A_Users_Email(ByVal strEmpId As String) As String
    Dim retVal As Object
    Using cn As New OracleConnection("Your connection string"),
            cmd As New OracleCommand("JOHN.GET_USERS_EMAIL", cn)
        cmd.BindByName = True
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add("User_Email_P", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Employee_P", OracleDbType.Varchar2, UCase(strEmpId.Trim()), ParameterDirection.Input)
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        retVal = cmd.Parameters("User_Email_P").Value
    End Using
    Dim returnString As String
    If retVal Is Nothing Then
        returnString = ""
    Else
        returnString = retVal.ToString
    End If
    Return returnString
End Function
```

Comment: I am not creating it. It's already there. I am using it. Even when I copy and paste your code, I am getting the same error (although the code looks very similar to mine)